Importing cell/wifi data into microG location provider
Version 0.2.29 of microG removed support for UnifiedNLP location provider back-ends (due to technical issues with newer Android versions), and instead built the functionality of some of these backends into microG. That includes the ability to scan for cell towers and WiFis in range and build a local database with them (formerly provided by the Déjà-Vu location providers) and the ability to query Mozilla Location Service (at least until that service was discontinued, but services with a compatible API would still work).
Now I am wondering if there is a way to import an existing database into microG to be queried locally (there used to be modules for mobile and wifi networks that could do this). Format is not that important – I can convert that as needed, if needed.
Unfortunately, since MicroG is a system app, I am somewhat reluctant to upgrading it just to find out, as I have never tried going back to an earlier version if something fails. The phone is my daily driver (i.e. production), not something I would want to carry out tests on.
So – does microG provide a way to import cell/wifi databases?
